# XML Attributes printing backwards in python

Tags: python, xml, elementtree

When I get a printout of the XML file using this code, it prints backward as shown below.

```
import os
import xml.etree.cElementTree as ET
import pprint

data_directory = os.environ.get('')


def taxRules():
    fileName = '/taxRules.xml'
    tree = ET.parse(data_directory + fileName)
    root = tree.getroot()

    data_list = []

    for child in root.iter("taxRule"):
        data = child.attrib.copy()

       # data['status'] = (data['status'])
       # data['rate'] = float(data['rate'])
       # data['range1'] = float(data['range1'])
        data_list.append(data)

    return data_list


if __name__ == '__main__':
    results = taxRules()
    pprint.pprint(results)
```

this is the printout but its suppose to print out
status, rate, range1, range2

Any idea how I can get it to print out exactly how it shown in the XML file?

I'm using python 3.8

```
[{'range1': '0', 'range2': '9950', 'rate': '0.1', 'status': 's'},
 {'range1': '9950', 'range2': '40525', 'rate': '0.12', 'status': 's'},
 {'range1': '40525', 'range2': '86375', 'rate': '0.22', 'status': 's'},
 {'range1': '86375', 'range2': '164925', 'rate': '0.24', 'status': 's'},
 {'range1': '164925', 'range2': '209425', 'rate': '0.32', 'status': 's'},
 {'range1': '209425', 'range2': '523600', 'rate': '0.35', 'status': 's'},
 {'range1': '523600', 'range2': 'max', 'rate': '0.37', 'status': 's'},
 {'range1': '0', 'range2': '19900', 'rate': '0.1', 'status': 'mfj'},
 {'range1': '19900', 'range2': '81050', 'rate': '0.12', 'status': 'mfj'},
 {'range1': '81050', 'range2': '172750', 'rate': '0.22', 'status': 'mfj'},
 {'range1': '172750', 'range2': '329850', 'rate': '0.24', 'status': 'mfj'},
 {'range1': '329850', 'range2': '418850', 'rate': '0.32', 'status': 'mfj'},
 {'range1': '418850', 'range2': '628300', 'rate': '0.35', 'status': 'mfj'},
 {'range1': '628300', 'range2': 'max', 'rate': '0.37', 'status': 'mfj'},
 {'range1': '0', 'range2': '14200', 'rate': '0.1', 'status': 'hh'},
 {'range1': '14200', 'range2': '54200', 'rate': '0.12', 'status': 'hh'},
 {'range1': '54200', 'range2': '86350', 'rate': '0.22', 'status': 'hh'},
 {'range1': '86350', 'range2': '164900', 'rate': '0.24', 'status': 'hh'},
 {'range1': '164900', 'range2': '209400', 'rate': '0.32', 'status': 'hh'},
 {'range1': '209400', 'range2': '523600', 'rate': '0.35', 'status': 'hh'},
 {'range1': '523600', 'range2': 'max', 'rate': '0.37', 'status': 'hh'}]
```

Comment: Why? You can of course print the dicts in any key order you like.

Comment: @AKX oh ok, Then my question is how do I print the dicts in any key order I'd like?

Comment: You have a list of dictionaries of some length N. You can reference any of the dictionaries by indexing your list with any value from 0 to N-1. Having said that, I suspect you don't want random access but rather you want them ordered. Please clarify

Comment: @ArthurKing yes I want them ordered. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: But again: why? What's your end goal here? Surely you're not just going to print the data as Python dicts to the screen?

Comment: @AKX it's for a homework assignment, I just need to print it to the console and need to print it in the order that its in on the XML file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason why it was printing the XML file unordered was because I was using pprint.pprint instead I used this to get the print I wanted in list view ....

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    values = taxRules()
    for v in values:
        print(v)
```

Answer (score 1):

It is a dictionary, so the order is not really important since you will access it by its key. But if you still want to print it in order, you can re-arrange it using this code.

```py
reorder_dict = [{x: d[x] for x in ["status", "range1", "range2", "range3", "rate"]} for d in data_list]
```

Extending this idea to your `taxRules()` method, you might do:

```py
def taxRules():
    fileName = '/taxRules.xml'
    tree = ET.parse(data_directory + fileName)
    root = tree.getroot()

    data_list = [
        {
            key: child.attrib[key]
            for key
            in ["status", "rate", "range1", "range2"]
        }
        for child
        in root.iter("taxRule")
    ]

    return data_list
```

Comment: This only works on recent Pythons which have a concept of dict key order.

Comment: Dictionaries preserve insertion order since 3.7. Python 3.6 reached "end of life" at the end of December 2021. https://endoflife.date/python

Comment: @JonSG so you're saying that if I'm using python version 3.8 it should preserve the order of the data in the XML file? and if so any clue why it wouldn't be?

Comment: @Junior Not exactly. What is preserved is dictionary insertion order, so this answer works as it creates a new dictionary to add to your list based on the keys in the order `["status", "range1", "range2", "range3", "rate"]`.

Comment: @JonSG I'm confused because I've printed attributes from XML files before using the method above and it would print the attributes in the order they're in on the XML file. Why is it different now? I thought there would be an easy solution to this.

Comment: Perhaps the `copy()` alters the order. Not sure.